Google OAuth Consent screen issue "Make sure your home page includes a link to your privacy policy" not being resolved after fix
I'm getting the "Make sure your home page includes a link to your privacy policy" issue on my Google OAuth consent screen section, in GCP. This results in having a verification status of "Pending developer action" rather than "completed".
I clearly have a link on my home page pointing to the privacy policy, it is accessible and visible, so why I'm getting this issue and how to remove it?
This is a screenshot of the issue on the GCP console:

And yes, the url of the privacy policy in my home page matches the one I've specified in GCP:

You can visit the app's home page if you want to inspect the html and confirm that the link is correctly there.

Did you able to solve this issue? I also got same problem and looking for solution right now.
